# UTF-8 only in Grails 1.1 database tables

Tags: mysql, unicode, grails, utf-8

When using Grails 1.1 together with a MySQL the charsets of the auto-generated database tables seem to default to ISO-8859-1. I'd rather have everything stored as pure UTF-8. Is that possible?

From the auto-generated database definitions:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Note the "latin1" part.

A work-around that works for Grails 1.0 is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481541/utf-8-only-in-grails-database-tables). This work-arounds does not appear to work when using Grails 1.1. The dataSource.dialect parameter seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the default character set of the database is used.

I solved this by creating the database with utf8 as the default character set:

```
CREATE DATABASE name_of_database DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was having similar problem where reading from MySQL was fine but writing converted some characters to "?" (question mark). This solved it: 
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your-db-name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8

mh23

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to same problem on StackOverflow:
[UTF-8 only in Grails database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481541/utf-8-only-in-grails-database-tables)

It have worked for me, however it's not elegant...

Comment: This is a link to an earlier question of the OP **and** he already linked to that in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add some properties to the Hibernate / JDBC url in your DataSource.groovy file. For example

> url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your-db-name?useUnicode=true"

MySQL has other parameters related to character sets as well. I'm not quite sure which and how many of them you need to get the expected behavior.

Comment: If the database's default character set is not utf8, this won't work.